# Using stripe connect with react native

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I'm currently looking to use the Stripe connect feature in my react native application and was wondering if there were any libraries I could use to use stripe connect. I've looked at react native stripe libraries like tipsi react native but it didn't seem like they support stripe connect. Is there a reference for api I could use to incorporate stripe connect in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best course of action when using Stripe in react native is to just use the native Stripe libraries.

This is due to the security vulnerabilities that exist when not using a Stripe approved library, and due to the lack of support for things like Stripe Connect and other services.

--UPDATE--
While I stand by the above for not using unapproved 3rd party libraries, I will say that Stripe does have an API that can also be used securely. In react native, that would be the way I would go about using stripe if I was not in need of the full Stripe libaries.